# Google Apps Script - How to get clipboard column number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Goal:** When a user pastes a value to a cell, I want the script to check whether or not the copied value is from the same column or not.

**Problem:** Oftentimes, the user copies a cell from a different column and pastes in a cell that's under another column. This causes some problems for this particular sheet, so I want to be able to have the script check if the clipboard’s copied value's column number (or letter) is the same with the column of where the user is trying to paste it.

**Example:**

- Scenario A: User copied a cell from A1 and attempts to paste it to B2 (either by mistake or intentionally)
  If statement check: Check if the user’s clipboard copied value’s column number (or letter) is equal to 2 (if by letter: B).

Result: Since the copied column number is 1 and editing column number is 2, the script will show an error message to refuse the editing.

- Scenario B: User copied a cell from A1 and attempts to paste it to A2
  If statement check: Check if the user’s clipboard copied value’s column number (or letter) is equal to 1 (if by letter: A).

Result: Since the copied column number is 1 and editing column number is also 1, the script will allow the user to pates the value to A2.

**Here's my attempt:** I thought it would make sense to use the onEdit function to compare

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const source = e.source;
  const sheetName = source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const column = range.getColumn();
  const editedRangeValue = range.getValue();


  // Call the copyPrevention function
  copyPrevention(sheetName, range, row, column, editedRangeValue);
}

function copyPrevention(sheetName, range, row, column, editedRangeValue) {
  const headerRowNum  = 12;
  
  if (sheetName == 'Status' && row > headerRowNum && editedRangeValue != '') {
  // row variable: This is to ensure the editing will only apply if the user tries to edit after row 12 (headerRow).
    if (column == "") { // The "" is just a placeholder. If this is even possible, I would like to compare user's editing column number & their clipboard column number. And if the column numbers are the same, then I'd like the script to continue the execution without throwing any errors.
      range.setValue(editedRangeValue);
    } else if (column != "") { // The "" is just a placeholder. I would like to compare user's editing column number & their clipboard column number. And if the column numbers are not the same, then I'd like the script to throw an error and not let the user edit the cell.
      const statusSheetUi = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      statusSheetUi.alert("You're pasting in the wrong column!");
    }
  }

}
```

I have a feeling that this isn't possible, however wanted to check.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your attempt? Or you just asking if this is possible theoretically?

Comment: @Kos Thank you for looking into my question. I've added my attempt, however, it's half theoretical as well...

Comment: right, you got your column number, what's preventing you from comparing?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the user's clipboard copied value's column number. How do we do that?

Comment: The `onEdit` trigger won't fire when copying. When editing the sheet, the "e" object will contain the range pasted into and the value pasted into that range. Perhaps you should think of a different way to allow your users to edit the spreadsheet. Perhaps use protections